# How to add and remove html element with java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have number of checkbox elements are there in my html page

```
<input type='checkbox' class='txtshow'checked="checked\" id='someid1' name='checkMr[]' value='some value' >
<input type='checkbox' class='txtshow'checked="checked\" id='someid2' name='checkMr[]' value='some value' >
<input type='checkbox' class='txtshow'checked="checked\" id='someid3' name='checkMr[]' value='some value' >
```

1. what i want is whenever any of this is checked dynamically one element input type='checkbox' should be added to html page.
2. if unchecked then remove the element which was added.
3. same element should no be repeated.

Comment: i am new to javascript and jquery so could not try. please help me out ?

Comment: javascript is programming laguage and jquery is a framework of javascript ... then search in google to learn about javascript ... there are many tutorials, guides and cookbooks ... and because you asked how to remove and/or add elements you have to learn more about DOM (Document Object Model) ... if you prefer to do this with jquery  search in jquery website for the documentation

Comment: I would suggest at least to learn the basics of javascript before using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the click event, check if the checkbox is checked.  If it is, then add a checkbox, if it is not checked, then remove the checkbox.  Use an id related to the parent to link them together:

```
$(".txtshow").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        newCheck = $("<input type=checkbox id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "-child' />")
        $("body").append(newCheck);
    }
    else {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "-child").remove();
    }
});​
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyZj6/6/

Comment: What to do if i have to append this to form element?

Comment: Change the "body" to the selector to the selector to which you would like to append.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$( '.txtshow' ).change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr( 'id' );
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $( '<p id="element_' + id + '"></p>' ).appendTo( $( 'body' ) ); 
    } else {
        $( '#element_' + id + ' ).remove(); 
    }
});
```

Where in this case you create a p element with that custom id. You can change that attribute as you want.